# How to search with Google API?

Tags: php, api

I would like to do a custom program that search on Google, I read there are APIs to do the queries, but Google is asking me a "website", I don't have a website, I only want to search on Google by a program that i'm developing in PHP (PHP_CLI).

How Can I use these APIs?

Comment: How about using `localhost` when generating the API key?

Comment: ok, but I don't want to use a web page...is it possible to do the queries with a command line application ?

Comment: What is the link to the API documentation that you read?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/). If so: I'm not really into that API, but afaik this API uses standard HTTP requests and in that case you can of course use the PHP CLI, too. Your PHP script just needs a layer doing the HTTP requests, e.g. s/t like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php), [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or even your own HTTP client class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you really mean, if you want to add Google Search into your HTML page, why don't you just create a form in which the action is pointed to Google Search?

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
    <input type="radio"  name="sitesearch" value="" />The Web
    <input type="radio"  name="sitesearch" value="yourdomain.com" checked /> My Site
</form>
```

Read: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_add_a_google_search_box_to_my_web_site.html

Is that what you're asking?

Comment: no, I have to use the API (old SOAP) the do the queries...As I read Google answers with a JSON stream. No?